# TokenResponseException: 401 Unauthorized When Trying to access Google Contacts Api

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-contacts-api

I am trying to connect to the google Contacts api to access my contacts/people that are saved in google but it throws a **TokenResponseException:401 Unauthorized**. I am somehow new to Google Oauth2.0. I already downloaded the Service Account Key File to my project root directory as required.

Below is the code:

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.gdata.client.contacts.ContactsService;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Connector {
private static ContactsService contactService = null;
    private static HttpTransport httpTransport;

    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "example";
    private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "example_mail@example-166608.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
    private static final java.util.List<String> SCOPE = Arrays.asList("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/");

    private Connector() {
        // explicit private no-args constructor
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getInstance());
    }

    public static ContactsService getInstance() {
        if (contactService == null) {
            try {
                contactService = connect();
            } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return contactService;
    }

    private static ContactsService connect() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

        java.io.File p12File = new java.io.File("example-e8135faedf4e.p12");

        // @formatter:off
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance())
                .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
                .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPE)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(p12File)
                .setServiceAccountUser("example@gmail.com")
                .build();
        // @formatter:on

        if (!credential.refreshToken()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed OAuth to refresh the token");
        }

        ContactsService myService = new ContactsService(APPLICATION_NAME);
        myService.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);

        return myService;
    }
}
```

However the following exception is thrown:

> com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 401 Unauthorized 
> **null**
>    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:105)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:384)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
>     at Connector.connect(Connector.java:58)     at
>   Connector.getInstance(Connector.java:31)  at
>   Connector.main(Connector.java:25) BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 9
>   seconds)

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [related thread](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client/issues/932), `TokenResponseException` could be caused by many things like invalid client ID, client secret or scopes and by refresh token overuse. It is also stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29967151/java-google-contacts-api-access-service-account-authentication) that another possible source for a "401 Unauthorized" exception is leaving the `credential.refreshToken()` away. The call is necessary to write the access-code into the reference.

Additional reference which might also help: [401 response when athenticating via Service Account and OAuth2 to GoogleDrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29277025/401-response-when-athenticating-via-service-account-and-oauth2-to-googledrive#comment46752988_29277025)

Comment: I am seeing this late but Thank you for the help. I was able to fix the problem, let me post the final code shortly

Comment: @MichaelGatumaSelvatico: What was your solution.

Comment: @MichaelGatumaSelvatico also Fermat found a simple proof for his last theorem but he didn't write it. That led dozens of mathematicians to madness for 3 centuries ahead.

Answer (score 0):

I see that your code is pretty much what is in the Quickstart samples. If this worked at least once, check if you have any token saved under tokens folder.